# Spring Cloud Aws kinesis Binder load balancing

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-aws, spring-integration-aws

I was trying to implement the load balancing for Aws kinesis stream consumers

As per documentation I am trying to implement

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      instanceIndex: 1
      instanceCount: 3
      bindings:
        RollUpInboundStream:
          group: my-consumer-group
          destination: my-kinesis-stream
          content-type: application/json
```

I have **3** containers, I want to bring up **new containers(At max 6)** if needed and without restarting the existing.

1. The instanceIndex starts from 0 or 1.
2. If I give the instanceCount as 6 but bring up only three instances, will all the messages are consumed until I bring up new instances.
3. In documentation, there is a property called spring.cloud.stream.bindings..consumer.concurrency, Can you help the importance of it.
4. For some reasons, if any of the instance goes down, will any of the messages be unconsumed.

Can you please help us

Comment: @Artem Bilan Can you help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `spring.cloud.stream.bindings..consumer.concurrency` is an internal option per consumer:

```
adapter.setConcurrency(properties.getConcurrency());
```

...

```
/**
 * The maximum number of concurrent {@link ConsumerInvoker}s running.
 * The {@link ShardConsumer}s are evenly distributed between {@link ConsumerInvoker}s.
 * Messages from within the same shard will be processed sequentially.
 * In other words each shard is tied with the particular thread.
 * By default the concurrency is unlimited and shard
 * is processed in the {@link #consumerExecutor} directly.
 * @param concurrency the concurrency maximum number
 */
public void setConcurrency(int concurrency) {
```

so, this does nothing with your distributed solution.

The `instanceIndex` and `instanceCount` works like this in the Binder:

```
    if (properties.getInstanceCount() > 1) {
        shardOffsets = new HashSet<>();
        KinesisConsumerDestination kinesisConsumerDestination = (KinesisConsumerDestination) destination;
        List<Shard> shards = kinesisConsumerDestination.getShards();
        for (int i = 0; i < shards.size(); i++) {
            // divide shards across instances
            if ((i % properties.getInstanceCount()) == properties.getInstanceIndex()) {
                KinesisShardOffset shardOffset = new KinesisShardOffset(
                        kinesisShardOffset);
                shardOffset.setStream(destination.getName());
                shardOffset.setShard(shards.get(i).getShardId());
                shardOffsets.add(shardOffset);
            }
        }
    }
```

So, every consumer gets a sub-set of shards in the stream. Therefore if you have more shards, than instances you may end up with the fact that some shards are not consumed.

There is nothing to consume messages from the same shard concurrently: only one thread can consume one shard per cluster.

Comment: Thank you @Artem Bilan. The kinesis stream is created with one shrad. Would the solution still works. Or The total shrads are referred from properties file.

Comment: Yes, solution will work, but all other instances will be in idle until the active one is dead. The producer `partitionCount` property is dictating how much shards you would like to have in the stream. Although in most cases we just rely on whatever is configure from the AWS environment and don't create or update streams at all.